# Bit shifting convert from C to Swift 3 using Bool

Tags: c, swift3, bit-shift

I have a piece of code in C and i am trying to convert to swift

here is the C code

```
long bitm;
long j;
long fftFrameSize = 2048;

for (i = 2; i < 2*fftFrameSize-2; i += 2) {

    for (bitm = 2, j = 0; bitm < 2*fftFrameSize; bitm <<= 1) {
        if (i & bitm){j++;}
        j <<= 1;
    }//eo for

}//eo for i = 2
```

From what i can understand my confusion is stuck at that C bool can also be a long.

Here is my attempt in swift

```
let fftFrameSize = 2048;

for i in stride(from: 2, to: 2*fftFrameSize-2, by: 2){
    j = 0
    bitm = 2;

    while bitm < 2*fftFrameSize {

        if (i % 2 == 0) { j = j + 1}
        j = j<<1
        bitm<<=1
    }//eo while

}//eo for i in
```

I'm pretty sure the stride code is correct. The first column in the following is what the C code produces for the first 33 values of j. The second column is what my code produces for the first 33 values of j. The values for bitm match in both so i have left out.
Thanks for reading

```
C    S

2    2
4    6
8    14
16   30
32   62
64   126
128  254
256  510
512  1022
1024 2046
2048 4094
0    2
2    6
4    14
8    30
16   62
32   126
64   254
128  510
256  1022
512  2046
1024 4094
2    2
6    6
12   14
24   30
48   62
96   126
192  254
384  510
768  1022
1536 2046
3072 4094
```

Comment: `if (i & bitm)` in your C code vs `if (i % 2 == 0)` in Swift ???

Comment: To clarify Martin's comment. The C code `if (i & bitm)` checks to see if `i` has at least the same bits set as `bitm`. Your Swift code `if (i % 2 == 0)` checks to see if `i` is even.

Comment: is there a comparable expression i can use in swift. if i try
 if (i & bitm){ j = j + 1}
it says 'Int' is not convertible to ‘Bool' any help would be appreciated

Comment: @oldman You can say `i & bitm != 0`

Comment: so the solution Hamish supplied was so simple and correct I don't know why i didn't try that. many thanks